# Java - Scroll image by mouse dragging

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jscrollpane, drag

I would like to make a join.me like in Java.

I've made the screen capture part but now I want to scroll in the image by dragging the mouse.

Here is a screen of what i've made:
[image]

First of all, I want to replace the scroll bars by mouse dragging the image. Is it possible?
Then I want to remove those scroll bars.

Today, users are able to change the zoom and use their mouse wheel to zoom in/out.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

---

Edit: I've found  the way to hide the scroll bar using:

```
this.jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
this.jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally, I did it myself. Here is the solution if someone need it:

Create a new class named `HandScrollListener` with the following code:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JViewport;

public class HandScrollListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    private final Cursor defCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
    private final Cursor hndCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
    private final Point pp = new Point();
    private JLabel image;

    public HandScrollListener(JLabel image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e)
    {
        JViewport vport = (JViewport)e.getSource();
        Point cp = e.getPoint();
        Point vp = vport.getViewPosition();
        vp.translate(pp.x-cp.x, pp.y-cp.y);
        image.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vp, vport.getSize()));
        pp.setLocation(cp);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        image.setCursor(hndCursor);
        pp.setLocation(e.getPoint());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        image.setCursor(defCursor);
        image.repaint();
    }
}
```

Then in your frame put:

```
HandScrollListener scrollListener = new HandScrollListener(label_to_move);
jScrollPane.getViewport().addMouseMotionListener(scrollListener);
jScrollPane.getViewport().addMouseListener(scrollListener);
```

It should work!

Comment: I would upvote you more than once if I could. Thanks for sharing!!